# Do same process on each image in the folder OpenCV python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I can't write the code on python to do same process in the folder.There are about 200 pictures in the folder,

The program uses OpenCV to analyze the ratio of blue color in an image.

Can anybody solves this problem?

Code reference:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread(direcory_and_filename_jpg)

hsv1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

binary1 = cv2.inRange(hsv1, (0, 163, 232), (255, 255, 255))

scum_ratio1 = cv2.countNonZero(binary1) / binary1.size

print('{:.2%}'.format(scum_ratio1))
```

The environment:

```
Windows10
python3.6.4
keras2.1.4
tensorflow1.8
GEFORCE GTX 1050Ti GPU
```

Comment: Have you used the command 'os.listdir()'? This returns a list of files in a folder. You could use this to get a list of the path names, and then iterate though them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` to get all jpg files in a folder

```
import cv2
import glob

files = glob.glob("Your_images_folder/*.jpg")
for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)

    hsv1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    binary1 = cv2.inRange(hsv1, (0, 163, 232), (255, 255, 255))

    scum_ratio1 = cv2.countNonZero(binary1) / binary1.size

    print('{:.2%}'.format(scum_ratio1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!   I tried like this below
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob


files = glob.glob("file_dir/*.jpg")
for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    
    hsv1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

binary1 = cv2.inRange(hsv1, (0, 163, 232), (255, 255, 255))

scum_ratio1 = cv2.countNonZero(binary1) / binary1.size

print('{:.2%}'.format(scum_ratio1))      The result was 0.14% only. I need the ratio for each images.So I thought the result should be 200 answers.like 0.14%,5.2%,18.3%.....I think my coding was wromg...Is there any error on my code?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the indent. Check out my edit answer.